# the result of assignment Logic operation

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

```
int  a = 5;
if(a = 5)
{
    cout<<"111111"<<endl;
}
if(a = 0)
{
    cout<<"22222"<<endl;
}
```

the reslut is

111111
Press any key to continue

acrroding to some commments，assign success，the result is true。

"a = 0" and a = 1" should assign success.but the result is only the first executed....

why ?

Answer (score 6):

Some comments? That seems dodgy and in this case is incorrect.

The result of `operator=` on `int`s is the value that has been assigned. In this case `a = 5` results in `5` and `a = 0` results in 0. Since `5` evaluates as `true` you see "111111" but since `0` evaluates as `false` you don't see "22222".

As for why assignment results in the value being assigned, take the case with multiple assignments:

```
a = b = 5;
```

This is the same as:

```
a = (b = 5);
```

So for this to work as expected `(b = 5)` must return 5.

Answer (score 5):

The result of `a=5` is `5`, and the result of `a=0` is `0`, so your program is like:

```
int a = 5;
if(5)
{
    cout<<"111111"<<endl;
}
if(0)
{
    cout<<"22222"<<endl;
}
```

Since the if statement requires a boolean value, `5` converts to `true` and `0` converts to `false` implicitly. so your program is now like:

```
int a = 5;
if(true)
{
    cout<<"111111"<<endl;
}
if(false)
{
    cout<<"22222"<<endl;
}
```

So it will print "111111" only.

> "**acrroding to some commments，assign success，the result is true**"
>   The result of assignment is the result of expression in the left side.

Comment: very good interpretation

Answer (score 0):

> "a = 0" and a = 1" should assign success.but the result is only the first executed....

Nope. `0` is false, you may as well have written"

```
if(0) { /* some code which will never execute */ }
```

The `if` statement evaluates the result of the *expression* between the parentheses, which means that the expression itself must be evaluated completely before the condition is checked.